# The ObservabaleCollection add/remove doesn't update the ItemsControl on the xaml side

Tags: wpf, observablecollection, itemscontrol

Lets say I have a class for my data:

```
class MyData
{
    public string FirstName {get;set;}
    public string LastName {get;set;}
}
```

And then in my view model I have

```
class MyViewModel : ModelBase // assume this has all the work behind for prop notification changes
{
    private ObservableCollection<MyData> addedData = new ObservableCollection<MyData>();

    public ObservableCollection<MyData> AddedData
    {
        get
        {
            return this.addedData;
        }

        set
        {
            this.addedData = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChangedEvent();
        }
    }

    public void AddDataRequestHandler()
    {
        this.AddedData.Add(new MyData() {some firstname and lastname}); //prototyping
    }
}
```

On the xaml side I have something like this

```
<Grid
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Button Grid.Row="0" Content="Add" Command="{Binding Path=AddDataCommand}" />

    <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AddedData}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FirstName}" />
                                <TextBlock Text=" - " />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=LastName}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

And assume that my Add button command request handler is properly tied to the handler in the view model (that works I can debug through it).

However, when I click the Add button and I can debug and see that the observable collection property AddedData gets items of MyData type added to it, still the ItemsControl doesn't show any of my items added to the stack panel. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Try to initialise your collection from ctor and raise property changed for the collection property. If that makes sense, cause you never notify that AddedData property has changed.

Answer (score -2):

My bad, I didn't notice that I have overkill nesting on the xaml side. So the ItemsControl should be much simpler as below and it works fine after:

```
<Grid
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Button Grid.Row="0" Content="Add" Command="{Binding Path=AddDataCommand}" />

    <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AddedData}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FirstName}" />
                    <TextBlock Text=" - " />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=LastName}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```